# (How) Can I execute a single .cmake file on windows?

Tags: windows, cmake

I am working on windows 7 with visual studio 2010.

I have a cmake building environment that does not work exactly like I would like it to. In particular, it executes a .cmake file at some point that processes all the correct files except one. I would like to run it manually to process the last file, can I ? How ?

(Details: the program I try to compile is opencv, especially the ocl module. The .cmake script I want to execute is [cl2cpp.cmake](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/cmake/cl2cpp.cmake))

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can run a cmake script with the -P option on the command line, e.g.:

```
cmake -P cl2cpp.cmake
```

Of course that scripts needs to be able to work stand-alone.

Comment: Thank you, I know this is somewhere deep down in the documentation, but to be frank I am scared by cmake and I don't dare going there...

Comment: Simply run `cmake --help` to list all officially documented Command Line Interface (CLI) argument. `-P <file>` is documented as "Process script mode.". I've checked this with version 3.1.0 of "CMake".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cygwin or WSL, you might also be able to add a shebang line at the top of your script and run the script from the command line:

```sh
#!path_to_cmake_binary -P
```